# How to display graphics objects behind or foreground of text inside QTextEdit in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting, qtextedit

I would like to display a rectangle behind a word I selected like Qt Creator does here:
[image: QtCreator does this when I select a word.]

I am experimenting with the example of QSyntaxHighlighter. I am able to change styles based on keyword patterns. I would like to have graphics or widgets for custom autocompletion lists.

Comment: Hi! What have you tried? How's your experimenting with QSyntaxHighlighter?

Comment: Well, i have this example and so far i encountered no problem:https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html

Comment: The image above is how Qtcreator looks and also how i WANT my app to look, so how can i render rectangles or other shapes(can i?) inside QTextEdit?

Comment: Have you checked out [QTextBlock](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblock.html), [QTextBlockFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblockformat.html), [QTextFrameFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextframeformat.html)?

Comment: No.I will check them out and see if they fit what i want to do.I'll keep the thread open for someone that has done this or was able to display graphics inside the QTextEdit

Comment: Hi there. I've posted a solution below that might suit your specifications. I have to apologise for my comment yesterday about checking `QTextBlock`, `QTextBlockFormat` and `QTextFrameFormat` as those 3 were not at all used in the solution I came up with. I apologise if I wasted any of your time. At the same time, I have to slightly _chide/remind_ you that you, the OP, should have done further research or attempted solving your question before posting a question on SO. Thus, both of us have something to improve on. :-) Check if my solution works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For autocompletion follow the [`Custom Completer Example`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-customcompleter-example.html) or the [`Completer Example`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-completer-example.html).

The code below follows the first one, which I blatantly, unashamedly copied and integrated into the `BackgroundHighlighter` class and `main.cpp`.

---

This answer will contain five files within a project along with a Qt Resource File.

1. `highlighter.h`  (Highlighter Class for Syntax)
2. `highlighter.cpp`
3. `backgroundHighlighter.h` (BackgroundHighlighter Class)
4. `backgroundHighlighter.cpp`
5. `main.cpp`
6. `res.qrc` (optional, not needed, you can hardcode your text)
7. `res` (directory) (optional)
8. `|- symbols.txt` (optional, you can set your own default text)
9. `|- wordlist.txt` (optional, copied from [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-customcompleter-example.html) but you could use your own line-delimited word list and set this in `main.cpp` with a [`QStringListModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html))

Note that the implementation of the `Highlighter` class for (1) and (2) can be found in the [*Qt Syntax Highlighter Example*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html). I will leave its implementation as an exercise for the reader.

In calling the `BackgroundHighlighter` class, one can pass it a file name to load text from a file. (This wasn't in the OP's specification, but was convenient to implement due to the large amount of text I wanted to test.)

Also note that I integrated the [`Custom Completer Example`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-customcompleter-example.html) into the class.

Here's `backgroundHighlighter.h` (3) (~45 lines, ~60 lines with completer):

```
#ifndef BACKGROUNDHIGHLIGHTER_H
#define BACKGROUNDHIGHLIGHTER_H

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtGui>

//  this is the file to your highlighter
#include "myhighlighter.h"

class BackgroundHighlighter : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    BackgroundHighlighter(const QString &fileName = QString(), QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    void loadFile(const QString &fileName);

    void setCompleter(QCompleter *completer);
    QCompleter *completer() const;

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e) override;
    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e) override;

public slots:
    void onCursorPositionChanged();

private slots:
    void insertCompletion(const QString &completion);

private:
    //  this is your syntax highlighter
    Highlighter *syntaxHighlighter;

    //  stores the symbol being highlighted
    QString highlightSymbol;

    //  stores the position (front of selection) where the cursor was originally placed
    int mainHighlightPosition;

    //  stores character formats to be used
    QTextCharFormat mainFmt;           //  refers to format block directly under the cursor   
    QTextCharFormat subsidiaryFmt;     //  refers to the formatting blocks on matching words  
    QTextCharFormat defaultFmt;        //  refers to the default format of the **entire** document which will be used in resetting the format     

    void setWordFormat(const int &position, const QTextCharFormat &format);
    void runHighlight();
    void clearHighlights();
    void highlightMatchingSymbols(const QString &symbol);

    //  completer, copied from example
    QString textUnderCursor() const;
    QCompleter *c;

};

#endif // BACKGROUNDHIGHLIGHTER_H
```

And here's `backgroundHighlighter.cpp` (4) (~160 lines, ~250 lines with completer):

```
#include "backgroundhighlighter.h"

#include <QDebug>

//  constructor
BackgroundHighlighter::BackgroundHighlighter(const QString &fileName, QWidget *parent) :
    QTextEdit(parent)
{
    //  I like Monaco
    setFont(QFont("Monaco"));
    setMinimumSize(QSize(500, 200));

    //  load initial text from a file OR from a hardcoded default
    if (!fileName.isEmpty())
        loadFile(fileName);
    else
    {
        QString defaultText = "This is a default text implemented by "
                              "a stackoverflow user. Please upvote the answer "
                              "at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53351512/10239789.";

        setPlainText(defaultText);
    }

    //  set the highlighter here
    QTextDocument *doc = document();
    syntaxHighlighter = new Highlighter(doc);

    //  TODO change brush/colours to match theme
    mainFmt.setBackground(Qt::yellow);
    subsidiaryFmt.setBackground(Qt::lightGray);
    defaultFmt.setBackground(Qt::white);

    //  connect the signal to our handler
    connect(this, &QTextEdit::cursorPositionChanged, this, &BackgroundHighlighter::onCursorPositionChanged);
}

//  convenience function for reading a file
void BackgroundHighlighter::loadFile(const QString &fileName)
{
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        return;

    //  the file could be in Plain Text OR Html
    setText(file.readAll());
}

void BackgroundHighlighter::setCompleter(QCompleter *completer)
{
    if (c)
        QObject::disconnect(c, 0, this, 0);

    c = completer;

    if (!c)
        return;

    c->setWidget(this);
    c->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::PopupCompletion);
    c->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    QObject::connect(c, SIGNAL(activated(QString)),
                     this, SLOT(insertCompletion(QString)));
}

QCompleter *BackgroundHighlighter::completer() const
{
    return c;
}

void BackgroundHighlighter::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    if (c && c->popup()->isVisible()) {
        // The following keys are forwarded by the completer to the widget
       switch (e->key()) {
       case Qt::Key_Enter:
       case Qt::Key_Return:
       case Qt::Key_Escape:
       case Qt::Key_Tab:
       case Qt::Key_Backtab:
            e->ignore();
            return; // let the completer do default behavior
       default:
           break;
       }
    }

    bool isShortcut = ((e->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier) && e->key() == Qt::Key_E); // CTRL+E
    if (!c || !isShortcut) // do not process the shortcut when we have a completer
        QTextEdit::keyPressEvent(e);

    const bool ctrlOrShift = e->modifiers() & (Qt::ControlModifier | Qt::ShiftModifier);
   if (!c || (ctrlOrShift && e->text().isEmpty()))
       return;

   static QString eow("~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?,./;'[]\\-="); // end of word
   bool hasModifier = (e->modifiers() != Qt::NoModifier) && !ctrlOrShift;
   QString completionPrefix = textUnderCursor();

   if (!isShortcut && (hasModifier || e->text().isEmpty()|| completionPrefix.length() < 3
                     || eow.contains(e->text().right(1)))) {
       c->popup()->hide();
       return;
   }

   if (completionPrefix != c->completionPrefix()) {
       c->setCompletionPrefix(completionPrefix);
       c->popup()->setCurrentIndex(c->completionModel()->index(0, 0));
   }
   QRect cr = cursorRect();
   cr.setWidth(c->popup()->sizeHintForColumn(0)
               + c->popup()->verticalScrollBar()->sizeHint().width());
   c->complete(cr); // pop it up!
}

void BackgroundHighlighter::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *e)
{
    if (c)
        c->setWidget(this);
    QTextEdit::focusInEvent(e);
}

//  convenience function for setting a `charFmt` at a `position`
void BackgroundHighlighter::setWordFormat(const int &position, const QTextCharFormat &charFmt)
{
    QTextCursor cursor = textCursor();
    cursor.setPosition(position);
    cursor.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
    cursor.setCharFormat(charFmt);
}

//  this will handle the `QTextEdit::cursorPositionChanged()` signal
void BackgroundHighlighter::onCursorPositionChanged()
{
    //  if cursor landed on different format, the `currentCharFormat` will be changed
    //  we need to change it back to white
    setCurrentCharFormat(defaultFmt);

    //  this is the function you're looking for
    runHighlight(); 
}

void BackgroundHighlighter::insertCompletion(const QString &completion)
{
    if (c->widget() != this)
        return;
    QTextCursor tc = textCursor();
    int extra = completion.length() - c->completionPrefix().length();
    tc.movePosition(QTextCursor::Left);
    tc.movePosition(QTextCursor::EndOfWord);
    tc.insertText(completion.right(extra));
    setTextCursor(tc);
}

QString BackgroundHighlighter::textUnderCursor() const
{
    QTextCursor tc = textCursor();
    tc.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
    return tc.selectedText();
}

/**
 * BRIEF
 * Check if new highlighting is needed
 * Clear previous highlights
 * Check if the word under the cursor is a symbol (i.e. matches ^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$)
 * Highlight all relevant symbols
 */
void BackgroundHighlighter::runHighlight()
{
    //  retrieve cursor
    QTextCursor cursor = textCursor();

    //  retrieve word under cursor
    cursor.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
    QString wordUnder = cursor.selectedText();
    qDebug() << "Word Under Cursor:" << wordUnder;

    //  get front of cursor, used later for storing in `highlightPositions` or `mainHighlightPosition`
    int cursorFront = cursor.selectionStart();

    //  if the word under cursor is the same, then save time
    //  by skipping the process
    if (wordUnder == highlightSymbol)
    {
        //  switch formats
        setWordFormat(mainHighlightPosition, subsidiaryFmt);    //  change previous main to subsidiary                     
        setWordFormat(cursorFront, mainFmt);                  //  change position under cursor to main               

        //  update main position
        mainHighlightPosition = cursorFront;

        //  jump the gun
        return;
    }

    //  clear previous highlights
    if (mainHighlightPosition != -1)
        clearHighlights();

    //  check if selected word is a symbol
    if (!wordUnder.contains(QRegularExpression("^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$")))
    {
        qDebug() << wordUnder << "is not a symbol!";
        return;
    }

    //  set the highlight symbol
    highlightSymbol = wordUnder;

    //  store the cursor position to check later
    mainHighlightPosition = cursorFront;

    //  highlight all relevant symbols
    highlightMatchingSymbols(wordUnder);

    qDebug() << "Highlight done\n\n";
}

//  clear previously highlights
void BackgroundHighlighter::clearHighlights()
{
    QTextCursor cursor = textCursor();

    //  wipe the ENTIRE document with the default background, this should be REALLY fast
    //  WARNING: this may have unintended consequences if you have other backgrounds you want to keep                 
    cursor.select(QTextCursor::Document);
    cursor.setCharFormat(defaultFmt);

    //  reset variables
    mainHighlightPosition = -1;
    highlightSymbol.clear();
}

//  highlight all matching symbols
void BackgroundHighlighter::highlightMatchingSymbols(const QString &symbol)
{
    //  highlight background of congruent symbols
    QString docText = toPlainText();

    //  use a regex with \\b to look for standalone symbols
    QRegularExpression regexp("\\b" + symbol + "\\b");

    //  loop through all matches in the text
    int matchPosition = docText.indexOf(regexp);
    while (matchPosition != -1)
    {
        //  if the position 
        setWordFormat(matchPosition, matchPosition == mainHighlightPosition ? mainFmt : subsidiaryFmt);            

        //  find next match
        matchPosition = docText.indexOf(regexp, matchPosition + 1);
    }
}
```

Finally, here's `main.cpp` (5) (~10 lines, ~45 lines with completer)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <backgroundhighlighter.h>

QAbstractItemModel *modelFromFile(const QString& fileName, QCompleter *completer)     
{
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
        return new QStringListModel(completer);

#ifndef QT_NO_CURSOR
    QApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::WaitCursor));
#endif
    QStringList words;

    while (!file.atEnd()) {
        QByteArray line = file.readLine();
        if (!line.isEmpty())
            words << line.trimmed();
    }

#ifndef QT_NO_CURSOR
    QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
#endif

    return new QStringListModel(words, completer);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    BackgroundHighlighter bh(":/res/symbols.txt");

    QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter();

    completer->setModel(modelFromFile(":/res/wordlist.txt", completer));

    // use this and comment the above if you don't have or don't want to use wordlist.txt
    // QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel(QStringList() << "aaaaaaa" << "aaaaab" << "aaaabb" << "aaacccc",     
                                               completer);
    // completer->setModel(model);

    completer->setModelSorting(QCompleter::CaseInsensitivelySortedModel);
    completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    completer->setWrapAround(false);
    bh.setCompleter(completer);

    bh.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

In `res.qrc` add a `/` prefix and add files (`res/symbols.txt`, `res/wordlist.txt`) from the `res/` subdirectory.

I have tested with a `symbols.txt` file resembling

```
symbol1 symbol2 symbol3 symbol4 symbol5
symbol1 symbol2 symbol3 symbol4 symbol5
symbol1 symbol2 symbol3 symbol4 symbol5
// ... ditto 500 lines
```

It takes about 1 second, which probably isn't ideal (100ms is probably more ideal).

However, you might want to watch over for the line count as it grows. With the same text file at 1000 lines, the program will start to take approx. 3 seconds for highlighting.

Note that... I haven't optimised it **entirely**. There could possibly be a better implementation which **formats *only* when the symbol scrolls into the user's view**. This is just a suggestion. How to implement it I don't know.

---

**Notes**

- For reference, I've attached symbols.txt and wordlist.txt on [github](https://github.com/TrebledJ/stackoverflow/tree/master/53318233/src).
- If you want to change the background colour of formatting, go to lines 27 to 29 of `backgroundhighlighter.cpp`. There, you can see that I centralised the formatting.
- `BackgroundHighlighter::clearHighlights()` might clear away any background highlights originally added as it sets the ENTIRE document's character background to the default format. This may be an unintended consequence of the result.

Comment: Could you provide me a symbols.txt and wordlist.txt cause i dont know what to put there.I tried:
symbols.txt:
"c cl cla clas class
in inc incl inclu includ include
class
include"

wordlist.txt:
"class
include
typedef
printf
int main{\n}
return
"
How is the completion list is triggered? with these files, i wasn't able to trigger it.The highlition works

Comment: Here you go: [_Link to Github Repo_](https://github.com/Technist/stackoverflow/tree/master/53318233). Err... completion is supposed to be triggered after entering at least 3 characters. If it doesn't work, maybe first try a separate implementation from [_the example_](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-customcompleter-example.html)?

Comment: Edit: I didnt put right the paths of these 2 files.Now it gets triggered by itself.

Comment: Hmm... so without typing, it pops up automatically?
In `main.cpp` try to replace the `setModel` implementation with `completer->setModel(QStringListModel(QStringList() << "aaaaaaa" << "aaaaab" << "aaaabb" << "aaacccc", completer));` and in `backgroundhighlight.cpp` fill in the default text with something feasible.

Comment: No i mean that now the completer gets triggered when i add 3 letters.It works well.Could you explain me the what does the symbols.txt does?Isn't the worldist the only thing i need for autocompleting?Whats the purpose of symbols.txt?

Comment: Good to hear that the autocompleter works well. (It's directly copied from the example. ) `symbols.txt` is a sandbox/test file for `I would like to display a rectangle behind a word I selected like Qt Creator does here.` It's not _really_ needed, you could load your own text. :P

Comment: I actually wasn't sure what it was you wanted. Whether it was the boxes behind the text or the autocompleter. So I included both.

Comment: One last thing.Do you know if i could style the background the background box of the highlighted text?Because in qtCreator the background box(as in my picture from the first post) is styled/has shadow

Comment: If you mean the color used, yeah, I made that handy for you by centralising it. Just change the brush/colours in lines 27-29 in `backgroundhighlighter.cpp`. Check out the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html), you can even make gradients (which is probably what you're looking for). Play around with it and see what you can do.

Comment: If you look closely in qt or zoom, the box has round boxes and perimeter.The code you provided me is a simple colored box.So i am asking if it is possible to style it(put it shadow,make it look 3d, make it rounded etc...)

Comment: Nah i get it.I can make a Qbrush with styles and then add it to QTextFormat and then inherit QTextCharFormat from QTextFormat.

Comment: Mhm, yea. But why inherit though.  You could directly call `.setBackground()` with a QBrush. Glad that you found this somewhat helpful. 

Comment: You are correct again:P You just QBrush gradBrush;gradBrush.setStyle(Qt::CrossPattern); setBackground(gradBrush);